# [Python][Kivy] Two Axes Scroll View in a Layout

Tags: layout, kivy, scrollview

I am very new to Kivy on Python and I am trying to make an android application.

Since the size of our mobile devices are not as huge and wide as the screen we use on pc,

I needed to make grid layout(table) and this should be scrolled both into x and y axis.

Could anyone give me a good working examples that are executable?

ex)This is somehow what i want it to be.

```
App():
    Screen():
       ScreenVeiw(vertical and horizontal movement availability)
              GridLayout():
                   Labels():
```

I would truly be grateful to your guidance and support!

Hope you all have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a working example of GridLayout with scrolling enabled in both x and y axes:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

APP_KV = """
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        size_hint: None, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        width: self.minimum_width
        row_default_height: 200
        col_default_width: 400
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:   
        Button:
"""

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(APP_KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```